# how to make pentaho bi server connection secure

Tags: security, tomcat, https, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to access http://localhost:8080/pentaho as a secure connection.

like

https://localhost:8080/pentaho

I am using bi-server-5.4
i tried to make changes in server.xml file

In ***connector*** i changed protocol="HTTP/1.1" to **protocol="HTTPS/1.1"**

after doing this changes server is not starting.

Note : 
i am using community version.

Comment: I put nginx with HTTPS in front, and just proxy internal. If you want to have HTTPS directly you need set it up with tomcat.

Comment: @bolav how to do it? can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Pentaho is running on Tomcat. You need to setup HTTPS in on your Tomcat. This is explained in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). If you still have troubles you should ask your question as a Tomcat question instead of a Pentaho.

To use nginx in front of Tomcat just add a proxy in your nginx setup, and then setup nginx with https:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```